# Equallogic two subnet's iscsi conection

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, iscsi

I buy one Dell Equallogic PS 6010, and don't buy fiber switch.

There are 3 servers, a domain controler with other financial software and yet another with sql server and IIS.

The DC and SQL server is connected whits equallogic by fibra channel, and the equallogic dont have order fiber channel.

My real problem is to connect the server via iscsi that this financial network 192.168.1.x LAN with fiber network 192.168.100.x.

DC runs Windows server 2003
Financial runs windows server 2008

[image: Network]

Sorry any erros types
Ty for any helps

Comment: There is no switch between the Equalogic array and the server?

Comment: NO. This is a problem and not have mor money to buy a switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need a switch (ideally two, for redundancy) between your storage array and your hosts.  Otherwise you're limited to the number of ports on your array.